Place with signs in Chinese & Arabic
A video about muslims had lots of still images presumably of muslims in different places.  One of them was people on a bus that had  sign in Chinese and Arabic.  No other languages visible.  The sign also had a graphic which I interpret as prohibiting hiding one's face.
Where in the world would I be likely to find signs like this?


It is worth emphasising that many languages are written using Arabic script, similarly to how many European languages are written using Latin alphabet.  Also the text is a bit blurred but you can maybe make out some additional letters which are not present in the Arabic abjad.

This is not Arabic, but the Uyghur language, spoken in what is currently administered by China as the province of Xinjiang; like many languages spoken by Muslims in Central and South Asia, it uses a modified variant of the Perso-Arabic script.
The sign prohibiting face coverings presumably refers to a niqab ban that China put in place in the region several years ago.; the image from the left seems to be about similar measures prohibiting "abnormally" long beards.

It looks to me that the first sign is prohibiting beards - something associated with Muslims (as well as Sikhs and ultra-orthodox Jews.  But context suggests Muslims in this case).  But I can't figure out the 3rd sign.

@PeterM is it "no swearing"?

@WeatherVane and PeterM, presumably no call to prayer

@Relaxed do you mean no answering a call to prayer heard from outside the bus, by unrolling a prayer mat in the aisle?

@WeatherVane So no praying? Honestly I don't know why any of this would specifically apply to a bus but at least that's what the pictogram seems to refer to.

@PeterM The 3rd sign is no explosives and no flammables.

@lambshaanxy I kept seeing the bottom right section of that sign as Goku's head lol

That's not Arabic, it's Uyghur, a Turkic language written in the Arabic alphabet and (when spoken) mutually intelligible with Uzbek. Thus, it's somewhere in Xinjiang (far west China)
